# Exporting a multigraph from ggplot to powerpoint with officer

Tags: r, ggplot2, plot, powerpoint, r-commander

somehow I am not able to properly export a plot containing three subplots into my PowerPoint with the `officer` package. I will most an MWE with the same but different data that produces the plot that I want to export

```
library(fpp3)
library(officer)
library(rvg)


p1 <- global_economy %>%
  filter(Code == "CAF") %>%
  gg_tsdisplay(difference(Exports), plot_type='partial')


#PPT
p_dml <- rvg::dml(ggobj = p1, editable = F)

my_pres <- read_pptx("...path/presentation.pptx")
my_pres <- add_slide(my_pres,layout = "Headline 1-zeilig", master = "Master-Design") #should be adjusted 
my_pres<- ph_with(my_pres, value = p_dml , location = ph_location_fullsize())

print(my_pres, target = "...path/presentation.pptx")
```

This is the graph that I am producing inside R:

[image]

But in the final PowerPoint only the lower right figure is displayed and not all three graphs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is that the object returned by `gg_tsdisplay` is not a `ggplot` object but a list of ggplot objects instead. As a consequence only the last element of this list is exported to the pptx or you get an error in the case where your first convert to a dml object.

One possible fix would be to build your multi plot using the `patchwork` package which as a side effect will "convert" the list of plots to a ggplot object. After doing so you could easily export to pptx whether as a `ggplot` object or as an `dml` object. In my code below I use `patchwork::wrap_plots` and use the `design` argument to mimic the layout of your multi plot:

```
library(fpp3)
library(officer)
library(rvg)

p1 <- global_economy %>%
  filter(Code == "CAF") %>%
  gg_tsdisplay(difference(Exports), plot_type='partial')

library(patchwork)

p1 <- p1 |>
  wrap_plots(design = "AA\nBC")

p_dml <- rvg::dml(ggobj = p1, editable = F)

my_pres <- read_pptx()
my_pres <- add_slide(my_pres,layout = "Title and Content", master = "Office Theme")
my_pres<- ph_with(my_pres, value = p_dml, location = ph_location_fullsize())

print(my_pres, target = "presentation.pptx")
```

[image]